# accessing the getOptions() of Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-config

I'm using the default `Zend_Application` design pattern which loads a zend config ini file automatically in the application bootstrap and I need to ini file's variables across many models and controllers.

Right now, I'm solving it by settings the config object as a key into `Zend_Registry`:

```
protected function _initConfig()
{
    $config = new Zend_Config($this->getOptions());
    Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);
}
```

Generally, I don't like using `Zend_Registry`, as it doesn't offer code auto complete in my IDE, and it's hard to keep track on what I have in the registry namespace.

Is there another way to access the Zend_Application's config ini?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a controller you should be able to do:

```
$this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getOptions();
```

to access the config. For models you really should be passing in the options you need. Otherwise your only choice is really the registry.

Answer (score 1):

You could always initialise it as needed yourself with

```
$options = new Zend_Config_Ini('/path/to/config.ini',
                               'config');
```

Wich is pretty much what the bootstrap does for you. Then you would have autocomplete on $options. But you would have to initialise it everytime you need it. 
I think modifying your code to suit autocomplete is not the greatest idea ever. But this is personnal.

If I am not mistaken with Zend Studio 8/9 (maybe 7) you DO have autocomplete even for objects returned by `Zend_Registry::get()`.